# JavaScript: how to set a value containing quotes inside a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC-project where I store data in a database and one of my views contains textboxes to edit this data.

Because of the specifics I can't create the textboxes directly via TextBoxFor(), EditorFor() etc. but have to affect the value with JavaScript, so what i do is write the needed value in the javascript code at page loading, and this code is later on triggered to affect the textbox value.

```
$("#textboxID").val("@HTML.Raw(Model.value)");
```

This workes fine until one of strings has got quotes in it.

When i input it directly like

```
$("#textboxID").val("@Model.value");
```

it will be HTML-encoded with the quotes written as `> & quot;` (without space of cource)

What i found out is that the only way to output quotes correctly is by escaping them with backslash `\` however i can't seem to find a helper to do that.
Is there a solution? Am i doing anything wrong?

For now, i found a workaround inspired by Filipe Borges suggestion

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.Libelle).Replace("&quot;", "\\\""))
```

It's very ugly, but at least it solves the problem, I appreciate anyone suggesting a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.value).Replace("&quot;", "\\\""))
```

First suggested replacing `&quot;` by `\"` using `@Model.value.replace("&quot;", "\\\"")`, but it does not work because the value only contains `&quot;` after the default html encoding is applied by mvc.

**Edit:** Final solution by Souhaieb Besbes. Edited mine to not keep it wrong.

Comment: i found out why, the value doesn't conatain &quot; initially, it's only after the default html encoding applied by mvc that the string &quot; appears, so this doesn't solve my problem.
 
however using @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.Libelle).Replace("&quot;", "\\\""))
did

Comment: @SouhaiebBesbes Great! Then post an answer your own question. It can help other people.

Answer (score 1):

For now, i found a workaround inspired by Filipe Borges suggestion

`@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.Libelle).Replace("&quot;", "\\\""))`

It's very ugly, but at least it solves the problem, I appreciate anyone suggesting a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quote to show double quotes as following:

```
$("#textboxID").val('"'+@Model.value+'"');
```

Comment: my problem is i want all symbols to be show well, i already tried this approach and the immediately thought to myself, what if someone inputs a single quote next time.

Comment: it doesn't matter and should work, check the following: 
text = "   'cdc'   ";
$("#textboxID").text('"'+text+'"');
will be working as well.

Comment: i think you're getting my situation wrong, i have a text value in the database that might contain quotes for example (stringwith"quote)

With mvc razor i write this value inside javscript code

so


$("#textboxID").val("@HTML.Raw(Model.value)");

becomes

$("#textboxID").val("stringwith"quote");

and this breaks the javascript code,

i hope i explained myself better this time

Comment: Yes, i understand that, why you think it will break

Comment: because it has a quote inside?